# Проблема в размещении картинок рядом. PHP

Tags: php, html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Нужно, что-бы логотипы были рядом друг с другом(шли в ряд)

Уже все перепробовал. Не могу понять в чем проблема

Код:

```
    if ($ability) {

        echo div('center');
        echo " <a href='?attack'>" . img('ability', 'attacked.jpg') . "</a>";
        echo "<br><div>Атака</div>";


        if ($ability['statusHp'] == 1 or $ability['energy'] < 1) {
            echo " <a href='?'>" . spell('ability', '5.png ') . "</a>";
            echo "<br><center>Зелье</center>";
        } else {
            echo " <a href='?UseSpellHp'>" . img('ability', '5.png ') . "</a>";
            echo "<br><div>Камень зелья</div>";
        }


        if ($ability['statusDef'] == 1 or $ability['energy'] < 1) {
            echo " <a href='?'>" . spell('ability', 'defence1.jpg ') . "</a>";
            echo "<br><div>Защита</div>";
        } else {
            echo " <a href='?UseSpellDef'>" . img('ability', 'defence1.jpg ') . "</a>";
        }
```

Comment: Можешь в инспекторе кода их посмотреть?

Comment: Перед и после div и center по умолчанию всегда делается перенос строки.

Answer (score 1):

Оберните ваши картинки в **родительский** блок и задайте ему стили.

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

---

**Flexbox**

```css
.parent {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.item {
    margin: 10px;
}
```

---

**CSS Grid**

```
.parent {
    display: grid;
    grid-template: auto / repeat(4, auto);
    grid-gap: 10px 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно использовать css, php тут не при чем, нужно добавить класс в див и написать что-то такое.

```
.img {
 display: inline-block;
 width: 200px; //тут нужно указать размер картинки
}
```

Код не идеальный, но должно сработать)

Answer (score -1):

Замените div на span. Различия очень хорошо [описаны тут](https://webref.ru/layout/howtocodeinhtml/chapter10).